# Can accelerating spaceship somersault in space?

Tags: angular-momentum, acceleration, free-fall

I was watching a space shuttle performing a pitch manuver in free fall, then I imagine a spaceship travelling with a constant acceleration in space trying to perform pitch manuver is it possible while experiencing no change in it's linear momentum?

Answer (score 0):

Sure. You just need two manoeuvring thrusters at equal distances from the spaceship's centre of mass and firing with equal thrust in opposite directions. These thrusters then exert a torque (turning force) on the spaceship but the net force on the spaceship is zero, so its linear momentum does not change.